# PowerShell type name evaluation

Tags: .net, powershell, scripting, powershell-ise, powershell-4.0

Unfortunately Powershell ISE can't show intellisense for .NET Classes Constructor.
I have found a script which can get the list of Constructor:

```
[System.IO.StreamWriter].GetConstructors() |
 ForEach-Object {
    ($_.GetParameters() |
        ForEach-Object {
            ‘{0} {1}’ -f $_.Name, $_.ParameterType.FullName 
        }) -join ‘,’
 }
```

It works perfectly

Is there a way to use a variable instead of a fixed class name ?
Somethink like that:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$class 
)

[$class].GetConstructors() |
 ForEach-Object {
    ($_.GetParameters() |
        ForEach-Object {
            ‘{0} {1}’ -f $_.Name, $_.ParameterType.FullName 
        }) -join ‘,’
 }
```

I will call the Script in this way:

```
Script.ps1 System.IO.StreamWriter
```

Now it return the following error:

At D:\LAB\POWERSHELL\CMD-LETS\GetConstructor.ps1:6 char:2
+ [$class].GetConstructors() |
+  ~
Missing type name after '['.
At D:\LAB\POWERSHELL\CMD-LETS\GetConstructor.ps1:6 char:26
+ [$class].GetConstructors() |
+                          ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a Type object from the $Class string argument:

```
$script = {
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$class
)

([Type]$Class).GetConstructors() |
 ForEach-Object {
    ($_.GetParameters() |
        ForEach-Object {
            ‘{0} {1}’ -f $_.Name, $_.ParameterType.FullName 
        }) -join ‘,’
 }
 }

 &$script 'system.io.streamwriter'

stream System.IO.Stream
stream System.IO.Stream,encoding System.Text.Encoding
stream System.IO.Stream,encoding System.Text.Encoding,bufferSize System.Int32
stream System.IO.Stream,encoding System.Text.Encoding,bufferSize System.Int32,leaveOpen System.Boolean
path System.String
path System.String,append System.Boolean
path System.String,append System.Boolean,encoding System.Text.Encoding
path System.String,append System.Boolean,encoding System.Text.Encoding,bufferSize System.Int32
```

Comment: Sorry I have forgot to add that i would like to call the script like this: Script.ps1 System.IO.StreamWriter. In my $class variable I will have a strign which represent the full name of the class Type.

Comment: Should work for that.  I updated the script with example usage.

Comment: Yes It Works, thanks!. Here another method I have just found: [System.Type]::GetType($class).GetConstructors() | ...

Comment: You could probably also replace `[string]$class` with `[type]$class`.